# Separate code rendering and jTab

Tags: feature-request, design

I feel like jTab and code snippets should be created and presented differently, have a look at the current design:

## jTab

[image: jTab]

## Code

[image: lilypond code]

In my opinion at least, neither design works. The text for the code blocks is too light (it looks almost fuzzy,) and the jTab background is too wide, and (I think) unnecessary.

I'd like to see this kind of output for each:

[image: jTab]

[image: Code]

The code is much more readable, and the jTab (I think) just looks nicer without the oversized grey background.

---

## Creation

Currently, you create both jTab and Code snippets by indenting with four spaces. I'd like this to be changed, to separate the two things completely.

Comment: Note that it is also possible to create code snippets across Stack Exchange using ` ` or the preformatted text button or using `<pre>` or `<code>`.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Then on Music.SE I think that should become the only option. Personally I'd love to see GFM's ``` (triple backtick) code-block syntax implemented on stackexchange.

Comment: What would you expect malformed jTab to display as, if not the raw code?  I don't think the syntax needs to change.  Completely agreed about the presentation, though.